# Show most recent row with given variable

Tags: php, mysql

The code below queries from a MySQL table with a "timestamp" type field called "time."

```
  $contest = "SELECT SUM(points) AS total, COUNT(points) AS total2, loginid, comment
               FROM contest 
              WHERE loginid = '$idn'";
```

**EDIT:**  I want to sum the points for all rows.  However, I want to display the comment from the most recent time stamp.  How can I do this in 1 query?

Comment: Use `orderBy` clause along with `limit` to achieve your goal.

Comment: just append  `and time > [the width you want]`

Comment: What do you mean by most recent? Is it only one row? Then the SUM & COUNT don't make sense because they use multiple rows

Comment: @user007 Good point.  I edited my question to clarify what I want.

Comment: @John Check if my updated answer works like you needed

Comment: @user007, yes it does.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT points, comment, timestamp
FROM contest
WHERE loginid = '$idn'
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your edited post:

```
$contest = "SELECT SUM(points) AS total, COUNT(points) AS total2
            FROM contest 
            WHERE loginid = '$idn'
            GROUP BY time DESC  
            LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: This solves the problem.  Thank you.  Someone else gave you that downvote.  I'm not sure why.  You were the only one who noticed the problem with the sum and count.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm just wondering who was the person who down-voted me without giving a reason >,>

Comment: Doesn't he want to display the latest comment?

Comment: Yes, indeed. What of it?

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness Yes, i do... and this answer does exactly that.

Comment: @John May I know if this has been solved or no? You had ticked as solved and then unticked again?